# iOS 10 Today Extension animate height on display mode change

Tags: ios, ios10, ios10-today-widget

I am struggling to set the height animated for the Today Extension when a display mode is changed. I have the following code:

```
- (void)widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange:(NCWidgetDisplayMode)activeDisplayMode
                         withMaximumSize:(CGSize)maxSize
{
    if (activeDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayModeCompact) {
        self.preferredContentSize = maxSize;
    }
    else {
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 165);
    }
}
```

It works, however the height of the widget is not animated, it just snaps to the new height. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: I had the same problem when testing in the simulator (no animation, it just jumped), but on the device it animated correctly. Were you testing this in the simulator as well?

Answer (score -1):

Override the following method and use the coordinator to animate the update

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
```

Comment: Are you saying that he should not set preferredContentSize in widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange:withMaximumSize: and wait until viewWillTransitionToSize? But will viewWillTransitionToSize even be called if preferredContentSize is not set?